# Hazelcast Predicate/SqlPredicate on Map of HashMap

Tags: hazelcast, hazelcast-imap, predicatebuilder

I have a Hazelcast Map of HashMap as values as I have shown below.

```
HazelcastInstance client = HazelcastClient.newHazelcastClient(clientConfig);
IMap<String, HashMap<String, String>> imap = client.getMap("users");

HashMap<String, String> value = new HashMap<>();
value.put("name", "name-1");
value.put("email", "naame-1@gmail.com");

imap.set("1", value);
```

I want to perform a query using Predicates/SQLPredicate. How can I do that?

Please help me.

Answer (score 0):

Unless there is a solid reason, you do not need to be storing a Map object as value. Looking at your code, you should rather create a simple POJO and store that as value. For predicates, check documentation here:

https://docs.hazelcast.org/docs/3.11.2/manual/html-single/index.html#distributed-query

Comment: Please let me know if the query on HashMap values is supported? If yes, how can I do it? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

There is no default built-in HashMap serializer for values, Hence, you need to write a wrapper object which implements one of the Hazelcast Serializations.